# Universal coefficient formula

Tags: homological-algebra, homology-cohomology

Let $X$ be a compact manifold (so that all (co)homologyies have finite rank). The universal coefficient formula ($\mathbb{Z}$-coefficient for simplicity) says that we have the following short exact sequence 
$$
0\rightarrow Ext^{1}(H_{k-1}(X,\mathbb{Z}),\mathbb{Z})\rightarrow H^{k}(X,\mathbb{Z})
\rightarrow Hom(H_{k}(X,\mathbb{Z}),\mathbb{Z})\rightarrow 0.
$$
This is a split sequence but the splitting is not natural but it seems to me that this splits quite canonically in case the coefficient is $\mathbb{Z}$. Am I right?

Here is my argument; since $Ext^{1}(H_{k-1}(X,\mathbb{Z}),\mathbb{Z})$ is torsion and $Hom(H_{k}(X,\mathbb{Z}),\mathbb{Z})$ is free. Thus it splits canonically as a direct sum of the torsion part and the free part
$$
H^{k}(X,\mathbb{Z})=Ext^{1}(H_{k-1}(X,\mathbb{Z}),\mathbb{Z})\oplus
Hom(H_{k}(X,\mathbb{Z}),\mathbb{Z}).
$$

Comment: Why is the split into torsion part and free part canonical?

Comment: I think that the torsion part of an Abelian group $H^K(X.\mathbb{Z})$ is intrinsic. It consists of elements $x\in H^K(X.\mathbb{Z})$ such that $nx=0$ for some $n\in \mathbb{N}$. The  free part is also intrinsic.

Comment: Identifying the quotient $M / Tor(M)$ with the free part of $M$ usually involves choosing a basis somewhere ($M$ = Z-module = abelian group). I don't think you can do this canonically

Comment: Really? Could you give me an example?

Comment: http://www.math.ku.dk/~gelvin/Modules.pdf, see proposition 4.8

Comment: You are right. There is no way to canonically identify $H^k(X,\mathbb{Z})/Ext(H_{k-1}(X,\mathbb{Z}),\mathbb{Z})$ with $Hom(H_{k}(X,\mathbb{Z}),\mathbb{Z})$. Thanks.